# Finding the number of multiples

Tags: problem-solving

I have recently been doing problem solving in math, and I came across this problem:

Determine the number of positive multiples of $6$ or $9$ or both, less than $1000$.

I appreciate any help.
Thanks!

Comment: Can you say how many multiples of $6$ alone there are between $1$ and $1000$?

Comment: Maybe taking 1000/6 and removing the decimal part would give you the answer, but I am unsure.

Comment: Should there be a comma after "both"?

Comment: Oh sorry, yeah I meant to put both, as in both multiples of 6 and 9

Comment: do you guys any clue as to how to set this problem up? appreciate your help. Thanks!

Comment: You could find the number of positive multiples of $6$ less than $1000$, and the number of positive multiples of $9$ less than $1000$. Add up these numbers. You could then subtract from this sum, the number of common positive multiples of $6$ and $9$ less than $1000$. The result will be your answer (why?). (*Hint*: A common positive multiple of $6$ and $9$ is the same thing as a common positive multiple of $18$.)

Answer (score 3):

The number of positive multiples of $6$ that are less than $1000$ is
$$\left\lfloor\frac{1000}{6}\right\rfloor=166$$
Likewise, the number of positive multiples of $9$ that are less than $1000$ is $$\left\lfloor\frac{1000}{9}\right\rfloor=111$$
Adding these, we get $277$, but we have counted twice the numbers that are multiples of both $6$ and $9$. So we need to count those numbers, then subtract from the total. Numbers that are multiples of both $6$ and $9$ are numbers that are multiples of the least common multiple of $6$ and $9$. That least common multiple is $18$, so we find:
$$\left\lfloor\frac{1000}{18}\right\rfloor=55$$
Then subtracting from $277$ we have the final count:
$$277-55=222$$